# UI Guidelines : Left Navigation button should be a previous button

Tags: ui, development

I've recently heard the that statement that the left navigation button should be a previous button and should not be used to display a menu.

Is that statement present in an offical guideline document or a WWDC video ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the WWDC video that's going that direction :

[Designing Intuitive User Experiences](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#211-video) (Apple iOS developer membership required).

Answer (score 2):

In an official [Apple HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Bars.html) there's the statement:

> When the user goes to a new level in a navigation hierarchy, two things should happen:
>
> - The navigation bar title should change to the new level’s title, if appropriate.
> - A back button should appear in the left end of the bar; it can be labeled with the previous level’s title if it adds value.

I do not recall any information about this in **WWDC** videos.